# Is there a list or API of Android device code names + brand names available?

Tags: android, api

I would like to get a list or API for code names for Android devices, so I can present a more human-readable view of what a users's device is, given only a code name. For example, the code name "d2vzw" is a Samsung Galaxy S III - Verizon edition.

NOTE: This is not a question asking for recommendations, favorite / preferred libraries, etc., and does not depend on individuals' opinions. I am looking for the location of a legitimate "master list" or database. This should be no different from asking about what API call to reference, or function to use, etc.

I'm looking for a list with information similar to what is at the link below, but not specifically related to CyanogenMod, and also it would be nice to get in JSON, API or some other relational format:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_supported_by_CyanogenMod

Basic attributes I need are:

- Manufacturer
- Model
- code name (obviously)
- Device type

Google Play seems to have all of this in their Play Store / application developers store, but I do not see a public download / APi available.

Someone must have done this before, but Google searches are turning up void.

Comment: This is not a question asking for recommendations, favorite / preferred libraries, etc., and does not depend on individuals' opinions. I am looking for the location of a legitimate "master list" or database. This should be no different from asking about what API call to reference, or function to use, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has a pretty extensive list of the official android devices released. I don't think all of them have a codename, but most of the major ones seem to be there:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Comment: Saw that. None of them has a code name. Thanks for taking the time to do a Google search ;-)

Comment: A few of them do actually, like Droid RAZR (XT910), Galaxy Y (GT-S5360), Galaxy (i7500), Infuse 4G (SGH-i997), etc but the list of far from complete. Some of the ones that don't have a codename in that list actually have it when you click on them and go to their own wikipedia entry...but doing that for each one would be a major pain lol

Comment: Hey, what about this? https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en